# Error in my switch case

Tags: c, arrays, switch-statement

So I'm trying to make an input function That takes in things separated  by a comma and puts each thing into it's own array. I think I almost have it figured with this switch, but it gets stuck in the second statement. I don't know why.

```c
/*************************************************************************

3/25/2015
This program takes in a file of the format
    PART,2.000,-1,0.050,V
    PART,0.975,-1,0.025,V
    PART,3.000,+1,0.010,F
    GAP,0.000,0.080
does the tolerance analysis
**************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define ARRAYSIZE 100
void input(char *gapPart, float *nom,float *tollerance,int *SIGNS,char *V_F,float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum);
void toleracningPt1(int size, char gapPart[], float nom[],float tollerance[],int SIGNS[],char V_F[],float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum);
int main(){
    /**Decs**/
    float nom[ARRAYSIZE]; //holds the nominal values (2.00, .975 ect)
    float tollerance[ARRAYSIZE]; //holds the third value (.05, .025, ect)
    int SIGNS[ARRAYSIZE]; // signifies if the value goes up or down
    char gapPart[ARRAYSIZE];// holds the value if it's a gap or part
    char V_F[ARRAYSIZE]; // F things cannot be changed, V things can be
    int size=0;
    float Spec_Minnimum=0, Spec_Maximum=0;
    /**custom functions**/
    input(gapPart, nom, tollerance, SIGNS, V_F, Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum);
    toleracningPt1(size, gapPart,nom, tollerance, SIGNS, V_F, Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum);
    return 0;
    }
 /***********************************************************************************************************/
void input(char *gapPart,float *nom,float *tollerance,int *SIGNS,char *V_F,float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum){

    const char *delimiterCharacters = " ";
    const char *delimiterCharacters2 = ",";
    const char *filename = "tin.txt";
    FILE *inputFile = fopen( filename, "r" );
    char buffer[ BUFFER_SIZE ];
    char *lastToken;
    int i=1, step;

    printf("File Data\n");
    /* usual error check*/
    if(inputFile == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", filename );
    }else{
        /**Prints out contents of the file **/
        while( fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE,inputFile) != NULL ){// while there is stuff to do this with
            lastToken = strtok( buffer, delimiterCharacters );
            while( lastToken != NULL ){//same song..
                printf( "%s\n", lastToken );
                lastToken = strtok( NULL, delimiterCharacters );// clear out lastToken
            }

        }

        rewind(inputFile);

         while( fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE,inputFile) != NULL ){// while there is stuff to do this with
            lastToken = strtok( buffer, delimiterCharacters2 );
            while( lastToken != NULL ){//same song..
                //strtok into seperate arrays
                while(i=1,i<5,++i){
                switch(i){
                    case 1:
                        fscanf(inputFile,"%s\n", &gapPart[i]);
                        printf("debug1");
                        ++i;
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        printf("debug2");
                        fscanf(inputFile,"%f\n", &nom[i]);
                        ++i;
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        printf("debug3");
                        fscanf(inputFile,"%d\n", &SIGNS[i]);
                        ++i;
                    break;
                    case 4:
                        printf("debug4");
                        fscanf(inputFile,"%f\n", &tollerance[i]);
                    break;
                    case 5:
                        printf("debug5");
                        fscanf(inputFile,"%c\n", &V_F[i]);
                    break;
                    default:
                        printf("Error");
                    }
                }


                }
                lastToken = strtok( NULL, delimiterCharacters2 );// clear out lastToken
            }
         }



        fclose(inputFile );

    }


/*****************************************************************************************************************/
void toleracningPt1(int size, char gapPart[], float nom[],float tollerance[],int SIGNS[],char V_F[],float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum)
{
    int x;
    float Act_Gap, Act_Tollerance, Maximum_Gap = 0.0, Minnimum_Gap = 0.0;
    for ( x=0, Act_Gap = 0; x<size; x++){   //does tolerance math
                Act_Gap = Act_Gap + (nom[x]*SIGNS[x]);
    }
    for ( x=0, Act_Tollerance = 0; x<size; x++){
                    Act_Tollerance = Act_Tollerance + (tollerance[x]);
    }
    for (x= 0, Maximum_Gap = 0; x<size; x++){
                    Maximum_Gap = (nom[x]*SIGNS[x]+tollerance[x])+Maximum_Gap;
                    Minnimum_Gap = (nom[x]*SIGNS[x]-tollerance[x])+Minnimum_Gap;
    }

    printf("Actual Gap Mean: %.3f\"\n", Act_Gap);  //printing
    printf("Actual Gap Tolerance: %.3f\"\n", Act_Tollerance);
    if (Maximum_Gap > Spec_Maximum){
        printf("The maximum gap (%.3f\") is (Greater) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Maximum_Gap, Spec_Maximum);
    }
    if (Maximum_Gap < Spec_Maximum){
        printf("The maximum gap (%.3f\") is (Less) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Maximum_Gap, Spec_Maximum);
    }
    if (Minnimum_Gap > Spec_Minnimum){
        printf("The minimum gap (%.3f\") is (Greater) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Minnimum_Gap, Spec_Minnimum);
    }
    if (Minnimum_Gap < Spec_Minnimum){
        printf("The minimum gap (%.3f\") is (Less) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Minnimum_Gap, Spec_Minnimum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mixing `fget()` with `fscanf()` is problematic.  Suggest one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to the use of

```
 while(i=1,i<5,++i)
```

instead of

```
 for(i=1;i<5;++i)
```

It works like this:

1. In the `for()` loop, the initialize is entered only once => `i=1`
   happens only once.
2. Check condition is used to exit the loop when the condition fails =>
   `i>=5` means exit loop; this is checked every time.
3. The increment happens at the end of every loop iteration => `++i`
   happens after the body of the loop is executed for each iteration.

Where as when you do a `while(i=1,i<5,++i)`, all 3 operations inside the `while()` happen in sequence in every iteration of the loop and this happens at the beginning.

Edit:

Move the line

```
lastToken = strtok(NULL, delimiterCharacters2);// clear out lastToken
```

One bracket above its current location.

Since the lastToken is never changing, the while loop is not exiting and hence looping over the contents again and again.

Solved errors in the code and added code below. Please use a diff utility like winmerge to understand each change:

```
/*************************************************************************
3/25/2015
This program takes in a file of the format
PART,2.000,-1,0.050,V
PART,0.975,-1,0.025,V
PART,3.000,+1,0.010,F
GAP,0.000,0.080
does the tolerance analysis
**************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define ARRAYSIZE 100

int input(char *gapPart, float *nom, float *tollerance, int *SIGNS, char *V_F, float *Spec_Minnimum, float *Spec_Maximum);
void toleracningPt1(int size, char gapPart[], float nom[], float tollerance[], int SIGNS[], char V_F[], float *Spec_Minnimum, float *Spec_Maximum);

char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
    char** result = 0;
    size_t count = 0;/* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    char* tmp = a_str;
    char* last_comma = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (a_delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token.*/
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller knows where the list of returned strings ends.*/
    count++;

    result = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)* count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = _strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(){
    float nom[ARRAYSIZE]; //holds the nominal values (2.00, .975 ect)
    float tollerance[ARRAYSIZE]; //holds the third value (.05, .025, ect)
    int SIGNS[ARRAYSIZE]; // signifies if the value goes up or down
    char gapPart[ARRAYSIZE];// holds the value if it's a gap or part
    char V_F[ARRAYSIZE]; // F things cannot be changed, V things can be
    int size = 0;
    float Spec_Minnimum = 0, Spec_Maximum = 0;

    size = input(gapPart, nom, tollerance, SIGNS, V_F, &Spec_Minnimum, &Spec_Maximum);
    toleracningPt1(size, gapPart, nom, tollerance, SIGNS, V_F, &Spec_Minnimum, &Spec_Maximum);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void printAllTokens(char** tokens){
    int j;
    for (j = 0; *(tokens + j); j++){
        printf("token=[%s]\n", *(tokens + j));
    }
}

void freeTokens(char** tokens){
    int j;
    for (j = 0; *(tokens + j); j++){
        free(*(tokens + j));
    }
}

int input(char *gapPart, float *nom, float *tollerance, int *SIGNS, char *V_F, float *Spec_Minnimum, float *Spec_Maximum)
{
    char delimiter = ',';
    const char *filename = "tin.txt";
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char** tokens;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    FILE *inputFile = fopen(filename, "r");
    printf("File Data\n");
    /* usual error check*/
    if (inputFile == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", filename);
    }
    else{
        while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, inputFile) != NULL){// while there is stuff to do this with
            strtok(buffer, "\n");
            tokens = str_split(buffer, delimiter);

            printAllTokens(tokens);
            if (strstr(buffer, "GAP") != NULL) {
                *Spec_Minnimum = strtof(*(tokens + 1),NULL);
                *Spec_Maximum = strtof(*(tokens + 2), NULL);
            }
            else{
                if (tokens){
                    for (j = 0; *(tokens + j); j++){
                        switch (j){
                            case 0: strcpy(*(tokens + j), &gapPart[i]);         break;
                            case 1: nom[i] = strtof(*(tokens + j), NULL);       break;
                            case 2: SIGNS[i] = atoi(*(tokens + j));             break;
                            case 3: tollerance[i] = strtof(*(tokens + j), NULL);break;
                            case 4: V_F[i] = (char)*(tokens + j);               break;
                            default: printf("Error");
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            freeTokens(tokens);
            free(tokens);
        }
    }
    fclose(inputFile);
    return i;
}

void toleracningPt1(int size, char gapPart[], float nom[], float tollerance[], int SIGNS[], char V_F[], float *Spec_Minnimum, float *Spec_Maximum)
{
    int x;
    float Act_Gap = 0, Act_Tollerance = 0, Maximum_Gap = 0.0, Minnimum_Gap = 0.0;
    for (x = 0, Act_Gap = 0; x<size; x++){
        Act_Gap = Act_Gap + (nom[x] * SIGNS[x]);
        Act_Tollerance = Act_Tollerance + (tollerance[x]);
        Maximum_Gap = (nom[x] * SIGNS[x] + tollerance[x]) + Maximum_Gap;
        Minnimum_Gap = (nom[x] * SIGNS[x] - tollerance[x]) + Minnimum_Gap;
    }

    printf("\nActual Gap Mean: %.3f\"\n", Act_Gap);
    printf("Actual Gap Tolerance: %.3f\"\n", Act_Tollerance);

    printf("The maximum gap (%.3f\") is (", Maximum_Gap);
    printf(Maximum_Gap > *Spec_Maximum ? "Greater than" : (Maximum_Gap < *Spec_Maximum ? "Less than" : "Equal to"));
    printf(") than specified (%.3f\")\n", *Spec_Maximum);

    printf("The minimum gap (%.3f\") is (", Minnimum_Gap);
    printf(Minnimum_Gap > *Spec_Minnimum ? "Greater than" : (Minnimum_Gap < *Spec_Minnimum ? "Less than" : "Equal to"));
    printf(") than specified (%.3f\")\n", *Spec_Minnimum);
}
```

**Output** of Gap calculation:

[image]

Comment: Note that I have replaced the `,` in your `while()` loop with `;` in the `for() ` loop.

Comment: can you add the content of tin.txt in the question please, so that i can run this program on my machine as well

Comment: Cool! I changed the '<' to '<=' and now it runs through cases 1-5 flawlessly.... forever. It never exits the loop.
Content is 
    PART,2.000,-1,0.050,V
    PART,0.975,-1,0.025,V
    PART,3.000,+1,0.010,F
    GAP,0.000,0.080
found int the upper comment block

Comment: Now it only runs twice, I think it should run four times (one for each line in the file)

Comment: updated the code again with changes to take Min and Max Gap from the input file.